# Como inserir um valor de desconto baseado em uma variação de ano? Exemplo: >2010=7% e <2010=12%

Tags: c

Desenvolvi um programa onde o usuário informará o ano do veículo e então o programa exibirá na tela o desconto referente ao ano. Ainda preciso adicionar um meio de perguntar se ele quer calcular novamente, se não, concluir. Posso fazer em Python se necessário.

O código que escrevi:

```
int
main ()
{
  int anocarro;
  printf ("Digite o ano de fabricacao do veiculo: \n");
  scanf ("%i", &anocarro);

  if (anocarro <= 2010);
  printf ("%i", "\nO desconto sera 7%");
  else (anocarro >= 2010);
  printf ("%i", "\nO desconto sera 12%");
}
```

Os erros foram:

> ```
> main.c:19:13: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 > has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat=]
>   printf ("%i", "\nO desconto sera 7%");
>             ^
> main.c:20:3: error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’
>   else (anocarro >= 2010);
>   ^~~~
> main.c:21:13: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat=]
>   printf ("%i", "\nO desconto sera 12%");
> ```

Comment: Não tem este `;` no final da linha do if (este ; está encerrando o comando if). Não tem sentido especificar um formato %i se não está imprimindo um número. Use: ` printf ("\nO desconto sera 7%");`. Você até poderia utilizar ` printf ("%s", "\nO desconto sera 7%");` mas não vejo muito sentido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você está dizendo que quer imprimir um `inteiro`(na verdade o `%i` é para informar que a base pode ser tanto 8, como 10 ou 16) e está passando uma `string`.

```
printf ("%i", "\nO desconto sera 7%");
```

Para saber mais sobre os `%` acesse esse [link](http://linguagemc.com.br/operacoes-de-entrada-e-saida-de-dados-em-linguagem-c/)

Uma maneira de resolver o problema do `printf()` seria substituir `%i` por `%s` ou colocar a `string` diretamente(`printf("Sua string aqui")`)

Agora o outro problema é refente ao `if` e `else`, é que como você não está colocando os `{}` á um [problema de ambiguidade](http://www.inf.ufpr.br/cursos/ci067/Docs/NotasAula/notas-5_Aninhando_sente_c_cas_if_.html)

Para resolver isso, você pode colocar os blocos(`{}`)

Fazendo as alterações o código ficaria assim:

```c
int main ()
{
  int anocarro;
  printf ("Digite o ano de fabricacao do veiculo: \n");
  scanf ("%i", &anocarro);

  if (anocarro <= 2010){
  printf ("\nO desconto sera 7%");
  }else (anocarro >= 2010){
  printf ("\nO desconto sera 12%");
  }
}
```

Comment: Faltou um ; que já corrigi. Fora isso, aparentemente não posso usar %, pelo menos com o compilador online que estou usando. Substituí pela palavra por extenso e funcionou. De qualquer forma, muito obrigado!